# Recursive definition of the Cantor Staircase

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots

I'm not the first one to try to draw the Cantor staircase, but I would like to understand why my code doesn't work. This is a minimal example :

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usetikzlibrary{math}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.18}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[
  evaluate={
    function cantor(\n,\t) {
      if \n == 0 then {
        return \t;
      }
      else {
        if \t < 1/3 then {
          return cantor(\n-1,3*\t)/2;
        }
        else {
          if \t < 2/3 then {
            return 1/2;
          }
          else {
            return (1/2+cantor(\n-1,3*\t-2)/2);
          };
        };
      };
    },
  }
  ]
  \begin{axis}
    \addplot+ [domain=0:1,samples=100] {cantor(0,x)};
  \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

The error message is

```
Runaway argument?
\ifx \tikz@math@meaning \tikz@math@meaning@null \let \tikz@math@next \ETC.
./cantor2.tex:33: Paragraph ended before \tikz@math@@getmeaning was complete.
<to be read again>
```

I would like to know what I did wrong. Any help would be much appreciated :-)

Comment: Your code doesn't work because of this bug: https://github.com/pgf-tikz/pgf/issues/847 Workaround: Choose another macro as a variable for `\t` that is not defined, e.g. `\m`.

Comment: It still gives me the same error message :-(

Comment: Right, it's actually much simpler than that. Change `},` into `};`.

Comment: OK, thanks, now it works. So I have the rest of the pgfplots to read for the graph to be less ugly :-)